# Security risk of PHP variables

Tags: php, security

The page I'm building interacts with the java api of another system to retrieve data via the command line. This is triggered from PHP, but needs a valid username and password sent with every call.

I don't want to store the username and password in either a file or a cookie, as I don't believe there's a way of doing so safely. However, I also don't want to make my users enter their credentials multiple times.

What I'm proposing to do is the ask for the username and password once, and store them in global variables in my php, using an `include` to make sure that all other php files had access to them.

My question is, is it safe to do this or would someone be able to view the state of the variables and discover the username and password?

Comment: Just store the values in a text file on the server, and eventually store them encrypted and compare crypted values.

Comment: @Virus OP needs to send them off to a third party application.  She can store them encrypted, but most likely needs to transmit them unencrypted.

Comment: Sessions can be useful in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use sessions. HTTP is a stateless protocol. If you have multiple requests with multiple clients, and you want to make it stateful (remember who is requesting), you need to use a session-based-solution: Put a session-id in a cookie on your clients system, send this cookie to your application on each request, and find out which data are associated with this session-id.

I know you want to avoid to "store the username and password" in a cookie. But I'm not absolutly sure if you know that in a php-managed session-based solution your session-data are NOT safed in a cookie. They can't be read out throughout the cookie. In fact, only the session-id is saved in the cookie. Your server then manages the reference between the session-id and all data in `$_SESSION` (which are only saved on the servers side!) - your user can't guess what kind of data is put into his session just because he reads out the cookies value.

The only security risk here is a session hijacking: Another person could try to steal your clients cookie to take over his session. But there are solutions for this scenario, just check them out and you will have a secure session-based solution.

Remember: If it comes to security, always try to prefer proven design patterns over developing your own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The variables will only be 'set' during the scripts runtime, after the script have ben ran, they will be the value they where set to default.
Ie. If you reload the page, the 'stored data' will be gone.

Take a look at sessions, might be the best solution.

Comment: I did consider sessions, but they store data in cookies which are easily accessible through the browser - not really what I was looking for. But thanks for this

Comment: If it have to be server-side, store it in any kind of database, load it each time its needed.